# GMail Addon: Expired Access Token

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

My gmail addon consists on several cards. For card navigation I widely use setOnClickAction, e.g.

```
CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('openUserCard').setParameters({userJSON: JSON.stringify(user)})
```

Gmail addon reference [says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action) both keys and values of `setParameters` method must be strings. That's why it's impossible to send any complex object from one card to another.

Global variables are not supported as well. One can use `PropertiesService` for storing some data, but that also restricted to strings.

I have initial and export cards. On initial card there's current email data importer that looks like that:

```
function buildAddon(e) {
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(e.messageMetadata.messageId);
  var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  ... we can do anything with attachments here...
```

The problem is that I have to use attachments not on the initial, but on the other, export card, to POST them to some external api. But I can not send `attachments` array directly using `setOnClickAction`, because it consists on complex objects with methods.

That's why I send the initial `e.messageMetadata` object to the export card, and there repeat all the operations above: `setCurrentMessageAccessToken`, `getMessageById`, `getAttachments`, and then for each attachment get it's content by `attachment.getBytes()` and send to external api.

If a customer goes to export card immediately, this all works. But if he browses some other cards for several minutes, and then goes to export, the call to `GmailApp.getMessageById(messageMetadata.messageId)` returns an error `Access Denied:: Expired access token`.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each action receives just one parameter, the argument 'e' event.

Then if we inspect that 'e', we will find a JSON object with the property parameters, which is the our parameters sent into the action function via the setParameters() method of the Action.

Inside this variable 'e' there is also a property called messageMetadata with all the proper values.

```
var myAction = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("xpto").setParameters({ name: "banana"} );

function xpto(e) {
    var name = e.parameters.name; 
}
```

A sample 'e' event has the following JSON inside:

```
{ 
    formInput = {},
    clientPlatform = web,
    messageMetadata = { 
        messageId= ... ,
        accessToken= ... 
    },
    formInputs = {},
    parameters = { name=Banana } 
}
```

Hope this is still useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It took some time to test, but it seems we haven't expired token issue anymore.